# Is there a way to sort/order 'FormCollection' key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

UPDATE:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "RSystem", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form_header" }))

{

    <fieldset>     
        <legend>Person</legend>     


@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "tblimportDevices" },
           rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            columns: grid.Columns(     
               grid.Column(header: "Location", format: @<input type="text" id="Location" name="location_@(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item))" value="@item.Location" style="width:250px;" />),
grid.Column(header: "Name", format: @<input type="text" id="Name" name="name_@(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item))" value="@item.Name" style="width:250px;" />)
         ......more.....
        ))
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I'm displaying data in a grid after user click on Save button (`POST`). 
I'm posting the entire form so that I can read the Grid data with key/value pair.

My question is:

Is that possible to sort the `FormCollection` key? the reason is that when I'm reading the `key/value` pair I need to know what is the last key/value I'm reading and based on that I have do certain actions.

Comment: Why not just bind to you model and post back the model and let the framework take care of all this for you?

Comment: will you show me an example where you can do bind grid( i'm using webgrid) to the model?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebGrid. But you manually generating inputs with `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model. Assuming you model is a collection of `myObject` that has a `Name` property then the `name` attribute should be `name="[#].Name` where `#` is the indexer. Then if your POST method is `public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<myObject> model)` the collection will be bound on post back (no need for `FormCollection`)